# change progress music when clicked on seekbar in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

hello all developer!

(this code is mediaplayer with seekbar)

the following code work properly but I want when clicked on the seekbar change progress music for example defalt musicplayer android

what can i do?

what add to my code?

```
public class DoaMatn1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageButton btndowndoa;
    ImageButton btnplaydoa;
    SeekBar seek_bar;
    Handler seekHandler = new Handler();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
    private static String file_url = "http://upir.ir/files92be/9e6cbb43de76.mp3";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.doamatn);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.fromFile(audioFile));
        btnplaydoa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnplaydoa);
        btnplaydoa.setOnClickListener(this);
        btndowndoa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btndowndoa);
        btndowndoa.setOnClickListener(this);        
        getInit();
        seekUpdation();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File audioFile = new File(sdcard.getPath() + "/EBKH/basem-tavasol.mp3");

    public void getInit() {
        if(audioFile.exists())
        {
            seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbdoa);
            seek_bar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btnplaydoa :
            if(audioFile.exists())
            {

                    if(mp!=null)
                    {
                       if(mp.isPlaying())
                       {
                          mp.pause();
                          btnplaydoa.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                       }   
                       else
                       {
                         mp.start();
                          btnplaydoa.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                       }
                    }
                }

            break;

        case R.id.btndowndoa :

            if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/EBKH/basem-tavasol.mp3").exists())          
                 new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);


           break;   
        }
    }

    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation();
        }
    };

    public void seekUpdation() {
        if(audioFile.exists())
        {
            seek_bar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if( mp != null && mp.isPlaying() ) {
            mp.stop();   
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("در حال دانلود،لطفا صبور باشید...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
        * Before starting background thread
        * Show Progress Bar Dialog
        * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
        * Downloading file in background thread
        * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/EBKH/basem-tavasol.mp3");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
        * Updating progress bar
        * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
        * After completing background task
        * Dismiss the progress dialog
        * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener to your class, then set the listener like this    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); and than implement these methods:

/***/

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch)
  {

  }

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
  {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
  }

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
  {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
  }
```

Here is a link of a fully working Media Player Example with seekbar touch listener and song progress update:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Regarding the tutorial the only thing that will not work is retrieving and filtering the song from the given file path. Somehow I couldn't get it to work. But I found another solution which was to write your own FileFilter. But in your case you are using a URL so that doesn't matter.